# Find rest of query string before a particular word in mod_rewrite file

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a url `/content/sell.htm?ld=a&id=b&_escape_fragment_=how-it-works` 
and want to redirect it to following url format `/details?pageIdent=<parameter after _escape_fragment_> & <rest of query string as it is>` using mod_rewrite.

So in this case server url would be `/details?pageIdent=how-it-works&ld=a&id=b`.

I have written following Rewrite rule for get parameter value of _escape_fragment_ but am unable to write rule to get rest of query string as it is.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)_escaped_fragment_=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/content/sell\.htm /details?pageIdent=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Could anyone help me in getting rest of query string and appending it to end of final url as it is. I hope I made some sense in explaining myself.

Also if someone could explain, what regex `(?:^|&)` denotes. I just copied it from somewhere.

Thanks

Jitendra

Answer (score 0):

Does passing QSA not give what you want? I'd be interested to know how that works when you already have args in your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/content/sell\.htm /details?pageIdent=%1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: QSA would append complete query string. I don't want to append _escape_fragment_ parameter again.